# What throwing weapons are treated as light weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

So according to the book, the two weapons fighting rules applied to thrown weapons are:

> The same rules apply when you throw a weapon from each hand. Treat a
>   dart or shuriken as a light weapons when used in this manner, and
>   treat a bolas, javelin, net, or sling as a one-handed weapon

However, there have been many more thrown weapons published since them (Chakrams for example, boomerangs). Just looking at the Fighter's "Thrown" category for Weapon Training:

> Thrown: aklys, amentum, atlatl, blowgun, bolas, boomerang, chakram,
>   club, dagger, dart, halfling sling staff, harpoon, hunga munga,
>   javelin, lasso, kestros, light hammer, net, poisoned sand tube, rope
>   dart, Shoanti bolas, shortspear, shuriken, sling, sling glove, spear,
>   starknife, throwing axe, throwing shield, trident, and wushu dart.

Is there a place saying what is considered a light thrown weapon, and what is considered a one-hand thrown weapon?

edit: if possible, I would really love having some RAW rather than houserules.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the weapon descriptions ([Pathfinder Core](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/equipment.html#weapon-descriptions), [Open Game Content](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons)), anything that has a Range is a thrown weapon (discounting projectile weapons like crossbows and bolts). Light and one-handed weapons are subcategories in those tables.

Comment: But that doesn't take into account weapons that are only in the Ranged Weapons subcategory, like hunga-munga, boomerang..

Comment: Hunga munga is described as a dagger, so use a dagger as reference. Boomerang is described as neither light nor one-handed so is neither.

Comment: So it's only through houseruling then, no official rules? Let's say I want to throw two boomerangs and have Two-Weapons Fighting, what happens?

Comment: TWF on thrown weapons: _The same rules apply when you throw a weapon from each hand. Treat a dart or shuriken as a light weapon when used in this manner, and treat a bolas, javelin, net, or sling as a one-handed weapon._ So you would need agreement that a boomerang counts as one-handed, which seems reasonable. However, if it's not a light weapon, the penalties are -4 and -4 instead of the -2 and -2 for a light off-hand weapon.

Comment: Actually, the only issue I have is that I was expecting some RAW rather than houserules (edited the question to take into account). Although if it is sure that there is absolutely no extended rule regarding Thrown weapons size, then...

Comment: I'd like to think my answer is RAW and these comments are interpretations on those rules and suggested houserules. The main problem is that a lot of these exotic weapons aren't clearly specced out.

Comment: @Cristol.GdM This answer is clearly RAW.  It may not be *helpful* but it is definitely what you asked for.  I don't think there are more published rules on this topic, sadly, so you'll probably have to use houserules for now.  You can post on the Paizo boards and hope for an official response though.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer It is RAW, but still doesn't really answer the question, as it is only applicable for melee weapons that are thrown... What is the SE policy in this kind of situation? Accept an answer that doesn't answer the question, or leave the question open even though an answer might never come?

Comment: @Cristol.GdM leave it open: also see http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/how-can-we-encourage-people-to-wait-before-accepting-answers and consider asking there for a real answer to that question.

Comment: What you're looking for, @Cristol.GdM, appears to be rulings regarding weapons released after the rules themselves were released.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going by weight and damage die. A [dart](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/ammunition-thrown-darts) weighs 1/2 lb., and deals 1d4, and is treated as a light weapon. A [javelin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/javelin) weighs 2 lbs. and deals 1d6, and is treated as a one-handed weapon. A boomerang weighs 3 lbs., and deals 1d6, so I would assume that it counts as a one-handed weapon.

Alternatively, you could state that any item that has a chance to be destroyed after use (or, in other words, counts as 'ammunition' when determining if you can retrieve it) would be considered a light weapon. [Darts](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/ammunition-thrown-darts) and [shuriken](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/ammunition-thrown-shuriken) are both defined in this way, and count as light weapons, though I can not be sure this is an official ruling.

Comment: The problem with using just weight is that unwieldiness of the weapon should be taken into account, in my opinion.

Comment: Which is why I suggested weight And damage die. If the damage die were larger, then it would mean that the weapon has more potential for damage, but also reflects a greater difficulty to wield. Thus why martial weapons deal more damage than simple weapons.